# how can I use data assets in azure ml registries in azure ml designer?

Tags: azure, dataset, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created some uri_folder data asset in my custom Azure ml registry.
Also, I have created some components in my registry.

When I want to create a new custom pipeline in Azure ML Designer, I can use my custom component, but I can't see my registered data assets.

How can I use shared/Registered data assets in designer in multiple workspaces?
Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate the question, whether data asset and ML designer pipeline are in different workspace? And see whether your data  asset is archived or not, because if it is archived it will be not visible.

Comment: yeah, data assets and ml designers are in different workspaces./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to access dataset in multiple workspaces.

Here, I created the data asset named  `sample` in workspace `jgsML` as shown below.

[image]

Then created new workspace named `jgsnew`  and created datastore linked to the previous workspace `jgsML`.
Below is the storage account in `jgsML`.

[image]

With this storage account I created data store in workspace `jgsnew`.

[image]

Click on create > Give a name > select storage account under workspace having data asset.

[image]

Then select the blob container where the file is.
To find this go data asset , there you will find storage uri as below, you can see under which container the file is there.
select that blob container while creating datastore.

[image]

Next select **Authentication type** as **Account key** and add your storage account key.

Below is the `sample` datastore I created.

[image]

After creating come to designer pipeline, drag and drop the
**Import Data** component and
Select **Data source** as datastore > select created datastore > select the path as below and click on preview schema to see columns.

[image]

And you will get the preview schema as below.

[image]

Like this you can access the data asset from multiple workspace.